# Cannot map a list to a widget

Tags: list, dictionary, flutter, dart

I have a hardcoded list that I want to map it to a list of widgets. The code below shows squiggly lines with the error `The return type 'List<ItemWidget>' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by anonymous closure.dart(return_of_invalid_type_from_closure)`.

```
.................MISSING CODE....................

ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => items.map((item) => ItemWidget(item: item)).toList();
) 

..................MISSING CODE....................

class ItemWidget extends StatelessWidget{

  final Item item;

  ItemWidget({this.item});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: FittedBox(
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            child: Image.asset(item.iconPath)
          )
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
          child: Text(item.name),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

EDIT:

This is the list of items, currently I hold just an item for testing purposes.

```
List<Item> items = [
  Item(name: 'Medicines', iconPath: '$ICON_BASE_PATH/medicines.svg'),
];
```

If you have any idea please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The issues is using the `ListView.builder`, the `builder` function expects you to return one `Widget` at a time corresponding to the index provided. Use `ListView` directly instead.

Example:

```
ListView(
  children: items.map((item) => ItemWidget(item: item)).toList(),
);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use **ListView.builder** then you can use as following. This may helps you.

```
body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items == null ? 0 : items.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ItemWidget(
          item: items[index],
        );
      },
    ),
```